# IOS modal segue returning black screen

Tags: iphone, ios7, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

I want to have a simple first view controller autofadeout to second view controller after 3 sec. What i did is inside the viewdidload of first, gave the sleep command for 3 sec and then used performseguewithidentifier. Now i am able to navigate to the second screen, however i its a black screen. Can anyone suggest what could be the mistake

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. When using segues i have experianced complete black screen on resulting viewcontroller. i have used contraints and i accedently added

```
 [self.view setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
```

in ViewDidLoad. On removing it, the segues work absolutely fine.